# Android application crashes when it starts

Tags: android, string, crash, android-edittext, logcat

I've made this application but when I try to lunch it he closes immediately.
This is my Principale.java:

```
package com.gabriele.progetti;

import android.R.string;
import android.os.Bundle;
import static java.lang.Math.*;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Principale extends Activity 
{
    private EditText edittext1, edittext2, edittext3;
    private TextView textview1;
    int A,B,C;


protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)  // Sarebbe come il main
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_principale);

    Calcoliamo();

}
// ;)



public void Calcoliamo()
{
    edittext1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    edittext2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    edittext3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3);

    A = Integer.parseInt(edittext1.getText().toString());
    B = Integer.parseInt(edittext2.getText().toString());
    C = Integer.parseInt(edittext3.getText().toString());

    int Delta = (B * B)*4*(A * C);
    double RadiceDelta = sqrt(Delta);
    String Risultato = String.valueOf(RadiceDelta);

    textview1.setText("Il risultato del deltà è:" + Risultato);
            setContentView(textview1);
}       
}
```

And this is my activity_principale.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Principale" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="35dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
        android:text="Inserisci a" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="numberSigned" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText1"
        android:text="Inserisci b" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="numberSigned" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText2"
        android:text="Inserisci c" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView3"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="number" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText3"
        android:layout_marginTop="46dp"
        android:text="" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText3"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView4"
        android:text="TextView" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

When I start it, LogCat says:

```
12-18 20:50:12.278: D/AndroidRuntime(326): Shutting down VM
12-18 20:50:12.278: W/dalvikvm(326): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
12-18 20:50:12.288: E/AndroidRuntime(326): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-18 20:50:12.288: E/AndroidRuntime(326): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.gabriele.progetti/com.gabriele.progetti.Principale}: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-18 20:50:12.288: E/AndroidRuntime(326):   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
12-18 20:50:12.288: E/AndroidRuntime(326):   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
12-18 20:50:12.288: E/AndroidRuntime(326):   android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
12-18 20:50:12.288: E/AndroidRuntime(326):   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
12-18 20:50:12.288: E/AndroidRuntime(326):   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-18 20:50:12.288: E/AndroidRuntime(326):   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
12-18 20:50:12.288: E/AndroidRuntime(326):   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
12-18 20:50:12.288: E/AndroidRuntime(326):   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-18 20:50:12.288: E/AndroidRuntime(326):   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
12-18 20:50:12.288: E/AndroidRuntime(326):   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
12-18 20:50:12.288: E/AndroidRuntime(326):   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
12-18 20:50:12.288: E/AndroidRuntime(326):   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-18 20:50:12.288: E/AndroidRuntime(326): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-18 20:50:12.288: E/AndroidRuntime(326):   com.gabriele.progetti.Principale.Calcoliamo(Principale.java:45)
12-18 20:50:12.288: E/AndroidRuntime(326):   com.gabriele.progetti.Principale.onCreate(Principale.java:24)
12-18 20:50:12.288: E/AndroidRuntime(326):   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
12-18 20:50:12.288: E/AndroidRuntime(326):   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
12-18 20:50:12.288: E/AndroidRuntime(326):  ... 11 more 12-18
20:50:14.208: I/Process(326): Sending signal. PID: 326 SIG: 9
```

Comment: You have a null pointer exception happening on line 45 of Principale.java.  What line is that? Look there.

Comment: You have not initialized textview1

Comment: I have textview1.setText("Il risultato del deltà è:" + Risultato), but if i delete it the app crashes anyway.

Comment: We cannot debug the entire application for you. Look at the logcat and it will tell you exactly where you have a problem. You probably still have a null pointer somewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you will need to first check EditText for Null or Empty before Parsing it to Integer as :

```
   if(edittext1.getText().toString()!=null &&
         edittext1.getText().toString().length() !=0){
    A = Integer.parseInt(edittext1.getText().toString());
     }
    else{
            // set default value here
              A=0;
      }
   if(edittext1.getText().toString()!=null && 
           edittext1.getText().toString().length() !=0){
       B = Integer.parseInt(edittext2.getText().toString());
      }
    else{
            // set default value here
             B=0;
      }
   if(edittext1.getText().toString()!=null && 
       edittext1.getText().toString().length() !=0){
      C = Integer.parseInt(edittext3.getText().toString());
    }
    else{
            // set default value here
              C=0;
      }
  //your code here
```

Comment: ahh but you do not need to check for this if you have initialized all of the elements in the onCreate() method, which he should be doing here

Comment: `.getText().toString()` portion will never be null. Instead, `edittext1 != null` is what needs to be checked.

Comment: @Eric : can you see code carefully he is calling Calcoliamo() method in on Create and parsing EditText Value to Integer. where  100% chance  value is empty or null

Comment: true, but the EditText objects will never be null since they are defined properly in his xml file. That is not causing his null pointer here.

Comment: @Joel : i'm not saying this is only error i see other answer which is also right because he is not initializing textview also . and in my answer i'm not checking EditText objects i'm checking EditText objects value which is by default null or empty

Comment: I say we just direct this guy to a basic java programming book and stop wasting our time pointing out every error in an error filled class.. haha

Comment: My point is that if `edittext1` is not null, then `edittext1.getText()` is not null, and `edittext1.getText().toString()` is not null. (By class definition.) But I agree with Joel... :P

Comment: @Eric : then what value we have in edittext1.getText().toString() ?

Comment: @Joel : if we use `String str= edittext1.getText().toString();` in current code then what value we get in `str`? as i known either `NULL` or `empty` ? which is not convertible to Integer

Comment: Well actually, a NumberFormatException will be thrown when parseInt() is called... The rest is legal

Comment: Edited as you said, but it still crashes. I could give you logcat if you need but the replies from @Joel aren't so motivating. If you consider a waste of time just say it to me and I'll delete this question.

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't mean to discourage.. Do you understand what the problem is? If you post your full activity code I can take a look.

Comment: @user109246 : delete it but first lean why your application is not working because it's important for you ok post new log and latest code also

Comment: @ρяσѕρєя K It would be more efficient to put that whole section in a try-catch block than to check each of those conditions..

Comment: @user109246 : plz post latest code and log also. you always welcome here if you have any same ,big or very low and very hight quality problem because this is only place where you get help as much as possible

Comment: @ρяσѕρєя K I will do it, but can we resolve this problem? Then I will return to study more carefully Java basics. I'll post the code tomorrow because I can't reply before 8 hours.
Thank you.

Comment: @user109246: well just post your code and log i will try to solve it and you will get your answer tomorrow from me or any other member.Thanks

Comment: I've solved it alone. The problem was in this lines:
textview1.setText("Il risultato del deltà è:" + Risultato);
setContentView(textview1);
I cancelled setContentView(textview1) because as logcat said "The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first"
Thank you for the patience, I promise I'll return to java basics books :D

Answer (score 4):

`textview1` is not set when you call `textview1.setText()`, you need to do

```
texttext1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
```

To guard against other errors, it is a good idea to check the results of findViewbyId to make sure they are not null before using them.

Comment: I've changed as you said, but the result is textview1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textView5). By the way the program still crashes.

Comment: Cut and paste error on my part, should be cast to TextView, see the edited text above.

Comment: @user109246 : program still crashed until you have not implement my answer also with this answer